# Using an Abstract Base class as an argument to a function (Python)

Tags: python

If I have an Abstract Base Class called `BaseData` which has the function `update` which is overridden with different functionality in its Child Classes, can I have a function as follows, where I want the function to take any Child Class as an argument and call the `update` function for the corresponding Child Class.

```
def date_func(BaseData, time):
        result = BaseData.update(time) 
        lastrow = len(result.index)
        return result['Time'].iloc[lastrow],result['Time'].iloc[lastrow-100]
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.  Python won't care because it doesn't do any type checking.

In fact, you can use *any* type that provides a compatible interface independent from whether the instance derives from `BaseData`.

Answer (score 0):

Including the name of the ABC as the name of the parameter won't restrict it to only subclasses of the ABC. All it does is make a parameter of that name.

Any object of any type can be passed in as an argument to any function or method. Any object that - in this case - doesn't have `update()` will cause an `AttributeError` to be raised, but if the argument has an `update()` method that can accept the one argument given, it won't cause a problem.

If you want to be certain that the first argument is a subclass of `BaseData`, follow these steps:

1. rename the parameter to something like `data`. This will make it so that the name of the parameter isn't shadowing ("replacing within this context") out the actual `BaseData` class
2. write `if isinstance(data, BaseData):` at the beginning of the function, tabbing everything that was already there over to be within it.
3. (optional) write an `else` clause that raises an Error. If you don't do this, then `None` will simply be returned when the type check fails.

Now that you know how to do what you're asking, you should be aware that there are few worthwhile cases for doing this. Again, any object that fulfills the needed 'protocol' can work and doesn't need to necessarily be a subclass of your ABC.

This follows python's principle of "It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" (or EAFTP), which lets us assume that the person who passed in an argument gave one of a compatible type. If you're worried about the possibility of someone giving the wrong type, then you can wrap the code in a `try-catch` block that deals with the exception raised when it's wrong. This is how we "ask for forgiveness".

Generally, if you're going to do type checks, it's because you're prepared to handle different sets of protocols and the ABCs that define these protocols also (preferably) define `__subclasshook__()` so that it doesn't JUST check whether the class is 'registered' subclass, but rather follows the prescribed protocol.